# How to change date format in column text file Windows

Tags: windows, scripting

I have a txt file with the following data in multiple lines:

```
10/01/2015,125.99,129.00,125.00,128.97,1615600
10/02/2015,129.92,129.92,127.01,128.81,509800
10/05/2015,129.50,130.00,125.50,126.37,876500
10/06/2015,128.00,131.70,128.00,130.67,1043000
10/07/2015,134.00,135.45,132.60,134.49,1181500
10/08/2015,133.90,133.90,131.60,132.25,736700
10/09/2015,135.01,138.50,135.00,137.80,1493200
10/12/2015,139.90,142.80,138.12,141.85,1879800
10/13/2015,138.80,139.50,137.75,137.99,1103600
10/14/2015,138.34,138.79,137.11,137.92,505200
10/15/2015,138.00,138.80,134.50,135.21,481600
10/16/2015,135.10,140.31,133.51,138.62,2431700
10/19/2015,138.51,139.89,137.50,137.94,521700
```

I want the date format to be changed to `YYYY/MM/DD` in all lines using a `.bat script`.

I have tried the following:

```
@echo off&setlocal
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,* delims=,/ " %%i in ('type "kam3.txt"') do (
echo %%k/%%i/%%j,%%l
)>"newfile.txt"
```

However, I only see the latest dateline being changed and rest of the data is not showing.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, if you are open for a powershell script, you could try this:

```
Get-Content data.txt | Foreach { $_ -replace "^(\d\d)/(\d\d)/(\d\d\d\d),(.*)",'$3/$1/$2,$4' }
```

Result:

```
2015/10/01,125.99,129.00,125.00,128.97,1615600
2015/10/02,129.92,129.92,127.01,128.81,509800
2015/10/05,129.50,130.00,125.50,126.37,876500
2015/10/06,128.00,131.70,128.00,130.67,1043000
2015/10/07,134.00,135.45,132.60,134.49,1181500
2015/10/08,133.90,133.90,131.60,132.25,736700
2015/10/09,135.01,138.50,135.00,137.80,1493200
2015/10/12,139.90,142.80,138.12,141.85,1879800
2015/10/13,138.80,139.50,137.75,137.99,1103600
2015/10/14,138.34,138.79,137.11,137.92,505200
2015/10/15,138.00,138.80,134.50,135.21,481600
2015/10/16,135.10,140.31,133.51,138.62,2431700
2015/10/19,138.51,139.89,137.50,137.94,521700
```

You need to run this in powershell (type powershell at command prompt, for ex.,). The `Get-Conetent` gets the content of the input file. The `Foreach` command iterates over each line. The `replace` command matches the regular expression and replaces the line with the matched variables (but in different order). If it is not clear, feel free to ask for clarification.

---

If you want different delimiters, use this command instead of the above. It doesn't look for a particular delimiter (like comma or semicolon).

```
Get-Content data.txt | Foreach { $_ -replace "^(\d\d)/(\d\d)/(\d\d\d\d)(.*)",'$3/$1/$2$4' }
```

Comment: Sorry but when I am trying the same code on my other file which has the following data:                       10/01/2015;125.99;129.00;125.00;128.97;1615600  
10/02/2015;129.92;129.92;127.01;128.81;509800  
10/05/2015;129.50;130.00;125.50;126.37;876500  
10/06/2015;128.00;131.70;128.00;130.67;1043000  
10/07/2015;134.00;135.45;132.60;134.49;1181500  
10/08/2015;133.90;133.90;131.60;132.25;736700  
10/09/2015;135.01;138.50;135.00;137.80;1493200  
                                                                                                                       it doesn't work

Comment: You have a new delimiter in this data (semicolon instead of comma). Use the new command as posted above.